# Why is the $\vec E$ field inside a sphere = 0?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, symmetry, gauss-law

I was taught Electric Field inside a sphere is 0, because of Gauss Law.

But inside a uniformly charged sphere, if I go at a distance of $r$ from the centre, I will be closer to the +ve charge and thus  a negative charge should experience a greater force, so the electric field should be non-zero. What am I missing here?

Comment: *"I was taught Electric Field inside a sphere is 0, because of Gauss Law."* This is incomplete. There are several ways it could make sense, but they all require a bit more foundation. Perhaps you could elaborate on the situation?

Comment: @dmckee So my teacher basically told me 3 things 1) inside there is no place for fields to end, so no field exists inside , there is no location for the E

Comment: The problem is that you haven't told us *under what circumstance* this is suppose to apply. I can certainly find some charge, draw a sphere around it and say "Ta da: sphere with charge in it meaning that it has non-zero fields inside". So this statement is not always true. So your instructor was talking about some specific situation, but without knowing what that situation might be we can only guess.

Comment: You would be closer to some charge in front of you, but now a greater proportion of the total charge is behind you.

Comment: Are you talking about a "shell" where shell theorem applies?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem